# How to get all text within node on same line using XPath 1.0

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```html
<a href="/company/10676229" 
   onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'SearchSuggestions']);"
   title="View company">
<strong>RECRUIT</strong>
" ZONE "
<strong>RECRUITMENT</strong>
" LIMITED               "

</a>
```

I'm trying to extract the text from the above a node in the form `"RECRUIT ZONE RECRUITMENT LIMITED"` - all on one line - but so far can only get them on separate lines. Since I'm running over a few hundred of these records, all with different patterns of bold and regular text it would be good if i can use an XPath expression to extract all the text on one line straight out, rather than having to use loads of logic afterwards to try and concatenate them together. Stuck with XPath 1.0.

I feel like there would be an expression to do this but struggled with research so far and not sure what else to try.

So far I've tried:

```
//a[@title="View company"]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

which returns a list but the text has been separated so all bold text is appearing on different lines to the rest for each a node

Comment: How did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

As already answered by @Andersson (+1), this XPath,

```
normalize-space(//a[@title="View company"])
```

will return

```
RECRUIT " ZONE " RECRUITMENT " LIMITED "
```

*for the markup shown in your question*.

In the comments, you've said that your actual markup will include multiple such `a` elements and that you'd like to select and similarly obtain the text for each.  **This is not possible with XPath 1.0 alone; you'll have to iterate over selected nodes and process them in the hosting language.**  In XPath 1.0, only the first of all such `a` elements will be processed by `normalize-space()`.

### XPath 2.0

XPath 2.0 can handle the task with this XPath,

```
//a[@title="View company"]/normalize-space()
```

which will apply `normalize-space()`, which first takes the string value and then trims leading and trailing space and consolidates interior space, for each node selected in the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

Try below to get text content of link as single string:

```
normalize-space(//a[@title="View company"])
```

Comment: since what i'm using is only xpath 1.0 compatible this only returns the first element, whereas i'm after that for every "a" node on the page (20). unless there's a way i can iterate through each and apply that to each a node individually?